# Continue logic in the LINQ query after anonymous type is created

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have a query:

```
    var query = from x in eksList
        // some joins and other things here ... 
        select new
        {
            Val = x.Something,
            Name = y.OtherThing,                    
        };
```

And then I do a `for-each` loop on my `query` and run some logic based on values on the anonymous object that I got.
so for example:

```
    foreach (var item in query)
    {
        if(SomeMethodCallResult(item.Val))
            myfinalList.Add(item.Name);
        if(SomeOtherLogic(item.Val) > 232)
            myfinalList.Add(item.Name)
    }
```

So my **question** is how can I combine this `for-each` logic into the original `LINQ` query so first it generates the anonymous result and then runs whatever the logic I am doing in the `for-each` right after that as part of the `LINQ` query.

**What I tried:** I did find the "`into`" keyword but still not sure how to run logic on that.

Comment: With your foreach doing some fairly complicated things (calling other methods, populating one of two possible lists) ... seems quite good to leave it separate, as it is.

Comment: @topsail believe me if it was up to me, I wouldv'e done the whole thing even in the first query in a for-each loop !  Just people more important than me what it that way.

Comment: @topsail  what if I break the IF into smaller LINQ queries and then UNION them ? hmmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was talking about in my comment.  By the way, this is how you prepare a *Minimal Reproducible Example*.

First a class:

```
public class Eks
{
    public int Something { get; set; }
    public string? OtherThing { get; set; }
    public string? YetAnother { get; set; }
}
```

Then a pair of *helpful* functions (using the names you proposed).

```
public static bool SomeMethodCallResult(int i)
{
    return i <= 2;
}

public static int SomeOtherLogic (int i)
{
    return i + 229;
}
```

Then the start of a test function:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var eksList = new List<Eks>
    {
        new Eks { Something = 1, OtherThing = "One", YetAnother = "Still One"},
        new Eks { Something = 2, OtherThing = "Two", YetAnother = "Yup, Two"},
        new Eks { Something = 3, OtherThing = "Three", YetAnother = "Guess it's three"},
        new Eks { Something = 4, OtherThing = "Four", YetAnother = "Four, not for"},
    };

    var query = from x in eksList
                    // some joins and other things here ... 
                select new
                {
                    Val = x.Something,
                    Name = x.OtherThing,
                };
    //note, "query" not materialized
}
```

Note that this is what you had.  At this point, `query` is an `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is an *anonymous type*).  I don't need to materialize it right now if I don't want to.  I could simply filter it like this:

```
    var filtered = query.Where(x => SomeMethodCallResult(x.Val) || SomeOtherLogic(x.Val) > 232);
```

And then I could take the filtered result (still not materialized) and pick out just the names:

```
    var names = filtered.Select(x => x.Name);
```

Now I have three *unmaterialized* collections.  I'm not sure what you want to do with them.  If you want, say, the original query and the names:

```
    var queryResult = query.ToList();
    var namesList = names.ToList();
```

Note that if all you want is the names, then just materialize the `names` query (only call `.ToList` on that collection).  You aren't creating three lists by going through the original data three times; you are going through the data exactly as many times as you call `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

The if statements will not work.  But here is an example if you did not have the if statements

```
var query = (from x in eksList
        // some joins and other things here ... 
        select new
        {
            Val = x.Something,
            Name = y.OtherThing,                    
        })
        .Select(x => new {val = x.Val, name = x.Name})
        .ToList();
```

Here is code with a Where

```
var query = (from x in eksList
        // some joins and other things here ... 
        select new
        {
            Val = x.Something,
            Name = y.OtherThing,                    
        })
        .Where(x => x.item.Val > 232)
        .Select(x => new {val = x.Val, name = x.Name})
        .ToList();
```

Comment: right.  But yes unfortunately I do have a couple IF in there to include.

Comment: what if I break the IF into smaller LINQ queries and then UNION them ? hmmm

Comment: Linq the Q stands for Query.  You cannot use Linq to ADD items to a list.   If you were adding to one list you could add a Where, but you are adding to two different lists.

Comment: @jdwent  : I am in real code adding to one final list indeed.  Just for posting on SO I changed it a bit not knowing it will affect the answers, so yes some logic runs, add to the a list,  some other logic runs, if it is true adds to the same list again

Comment: I added a method with a where.

Comment: Why not just OR the two IFs in the WHERE clause, something like: `.Where(x => SomeMethodCallResult(x.Val) || SomeOtherLogic(x.Val) > 232)`.  This won't work if you are using a direct database LINQ technology, but it should work if `eksList` is just a list of objects.

Comment: @Flydog57 : I just created a simple Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a `Where` and a `Select` to build a list of names. At least in the reduced code shown. The anonymous type as intermediate data vehicle could make things clearer - or unnecessarily complicated. Depends on the real query, which is likely more complex than the sample code.

```
var nameList = (from x in eksList
// some joins and other things here ... 
where (SomeMethodCallResult(x.Something) || SomeOtherLogic(x.Something) > 232)
select y.OtherThing).ToList();
```